# VB.net IO.Directory.CreateDirectory

Tags: vb.net, directory, readonly

When I use `IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` to create a directory it creates a read-only directory no matter where I make the directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: There is no such thing as a read-only directory.  What is your precise problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused by the shell properties dialog:

[image]

The Read-only checkbox is a tristate checkbox.  When it is filled solid like that, it means the state is "indeterminate'.  Click it twice to turn it into a check mark.  When you then hit the OK or Apply button, the shell sets the readonly attribute on all the files inside the folder.

Yes, this is not great UI design, you are not the first to be tripped up by this.  The (only applies to files in folder) hint looks like a fairly desperate attempt to make it clearer.  Without enough room to make it a grammatically correct phrase.  Wonder what it looks like in German...

Comment: Thanks for your help. It turns out it wasn't a problem with creating a folder but my ineptitude with writeallbytes...you have to specify a file name and extension in the path...my bad.